# Example of a 3x3 Matrix with no inverse, where the row totals add to 1, and no duplicate rows

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations

Is it possible to have a 3x3 matrix that has no inverse, where the row totals  add up to 1, and there are no duplicate rows? And, can this be extended to an nxn matrix? I am inclined to say no, because in order for a matrix to have no inverse, the rows must be linearly dependent? Every example I can think of, yields a matrix that has row totals that add up to 1, but there are duplicate rows.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: Do you mean the total of every row is 1? What you said was that adding up the three row totals (same as adding the nine numbers in the matrix) gives 1.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

In $\mathbb{R}^2$, the set of vectors $(0.1,0.9), (0.2,0.8), (0.3,0.7)$ is certainly linearly dependent even though each vector's coordinates add up to $1$. Can you think of them as vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$?